# Error on running pod install --repo-update after installing Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native

I try to install Firebase in a react native app but i keep getting errors when I run pod install --repo-update.

This is the error:

```
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Core":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Core (= 6.22.0)

  In Podfile:
    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 6.7.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (~> 6.13.0)


You have either:
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Core` inside your development pod `RNFBApp`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/Core` to apply changes you've made.
```

I searched similar problem resolutions and I already tried replacing Firebase/Core with - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6) but that didn't help.

This is my podfile:

---

```
PODS:
  - boost-for-react-native (1.63.0)
  - CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.4)
  - CocoaLibEvent (1.0.0)
  - DoubleConversion (1.1.6)
  - FBLazyVector (0.62.2)
  - FBReactNativeSpec (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - RCTRequired (= 0.62.2)
    - RCTTypeSafety (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - Firebase/Analytics (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/Core
  - Firebase/Core (6.22.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.4.1)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (6.22.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 6.6.6)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (6.4.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - FirebaseInstallations (~> 1.1)
    - GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.4.1)
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - FirebaseCore (6.6.6):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 1.2)
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.2.3):
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (~> 2.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 6.5)
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 6.5)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.2.0)
  - FirebaseInstallations (1.1.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 6.6)
    - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 6.5)
    - PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
  - Flipper (0.33.1):
    - Flipper-Folly (~> 2.1)
    - Flipper-RSocket (~> 1.0)
  - Flipper-DoubleConversion (1.1.7)
  - Flipper-Folly (2.2.0):
    - boost-for-react-native
    - CocoaLibEvent (~> 1.0)
    - Flipper-DoubleConversion
    - Flipper-Glog
    - OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.0.2.19)
  - Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)
  - Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)
  - Flipper-RSocket (1.1.0):
    - Flipper-Folly (~> 2.2)
  - FlipperKit (0.33.1):
    - FlipperKit/Core (= 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/Core (0.33.1):
    - Flipper (~> 0.33.1)
    - FlipperKit/CppBridge
    - FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert
    - FlipperKit/FBDefines
    - FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding
  - FlipperKit/CppBridge (0.33.1):
    - Flipper (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert (0.33.1):
    - Flipper-Folly (~> 2.1)
  - FlipperKit/FBDefines (0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding (0.33.1):
    - CocoaAsyncSocket (~> 7.6)
    - Flipper-PeerTalk (~> 0.0.4)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay (0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin (0.33.1):
    - FlipperKit/Core
    - FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay
    - FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable
    - YogaKit (~> 1.18)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable (0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin (0.33.1):
    - FlipperKit/Core
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin (0.33.1):
    - FlipperKit/Core
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin (0.33.1):
    - FlipperKit/Core
  - FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin (0.33.1):
    - FlipperKit/Core
    - FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin
  - Folly (2018.10.22.00):
    - boost-for-react-native
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly/Default (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
  - Folly/Default (2018.10.22.00):
    - boost-for-react-native
    - DoubleConversion
    - glog
  - glog (0.3.5)
  - GoogleAppMeasurement (6.4.1):
    - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 6.0)
    - GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 6.0)
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 6.0)"
    - nanopb (= 0.3.9011)
  - GoogleDataTransport (5.1.1)
  - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (2.0.3):
    - GoogleDataTransport (~> 5.1)
    - nanopb (~> 0.3.901)
  - GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - GoogleUtilities/Network
  - GoogleUtilities/Environment (6.5.2)
  - GoogleUtilities/Logger (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Environment
  - GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/Network (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
    - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib"
    - GoogleUtilities/Reachability
  - "GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (6.5.2)"
  - GoogleUtilities/Reachability (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (6.5.2):
    - GoogleUtilities/Logger
  - nanopb (0.3.9011):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.9011)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.9011)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.9011)
  - OpenSSL-Universal (1.0.2.19):
    - OpenSSL-Universal/Static (= 1.0.2.19)
  - OpenSSL-Universal/Static (1.0.2.19)
  - PromisesObjC (1.2.8)
  - RCTRequired (0.62.2)
  - RCTTypeSafety (0.62.2):
    - FBLazyVector (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - RCTRequired (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core (= 0.62.2)
  - React (0.62.2):
    - React-Core (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/DevSupport (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTWebSocket (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTActionSheet (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTAnimation (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTBlob (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTImage (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTLinking (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTNetwork (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTSettings (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTText (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTVibration (= 0.62.2)
  - React-Core (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default (= 0.62.2)
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/CoreModulesHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/Default (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/DevSupport (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTWebSocket (= 0.62.2)
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsinspector (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTActionSheetHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTAnimationHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTBlobHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTImageHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTLinkingHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTNetworkHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTSettingsHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTTextHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTVibrationHeaders (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-Core/RCTWebSocket (0.62.2):
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core/Default (= 0.62.2)
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsiexecutor (= 0.62.2)
    - Yoga
  - React-CoreModules (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - RCTTypeSafety (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/CoreModulesHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTImage (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - React-cxxreact (0.62.2):
    - boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-jsinspector (= 0.62.2)
  - React-jsi (0.62.2):
    - boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-jsi/Default (= 0.62.2)
  - React-jsi/Default (0.62.2):
    - boost-for-react-native (= 1.63.0)
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
  - React-jsiexecutor (0.62.2):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
  - React-jsinspector (0.62.2)
  - react-native-safe-area-context (0.7.3):
    - React
  - React-RCTActionSheet (0.62.2):
    - React-Core/RCTActionSheetHeaders (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTAnimation (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - RCTTypeSafety (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTAnimationHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTBlob (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - React-Core/RCTBlobHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTWebSocket (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTNetwork (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTImage (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - RCTTypeSafety (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTImageHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - React-RCTNetwork (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTLinking (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTLinkingHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTNetwork (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - RCTTypeSafety (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTNetworkHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTSettings (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - RCTTypeSafety (= 0.62.2)
    - React-Core/RCTSettingsHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTText (0.62.2):
    - React-Core/RCTTextHeaders (= 0.62.2)
  - React-RCTVibration (0.62.2):
    - FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.62.2)
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - React-Core/RCTVibrationHeaders (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.62.2)
  - ReactCommon/callinvoker (0.62.2):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
  - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (0.62.2):
    - DoubleConversion
    - Folly (= 2018.10.22.00)
    - glog
    - React-Core (= 0.62.2)
    - React-cxxreact (= 0.62.2)
    - React-jsi (= 0.62.2)
    - ReactCommon/callinvoker (= 0.62.2)
  - RNCMaskedView (0.1.9):
    - React
  - RNGestureHandler (1.6.1):
    - React
  - RNReanimated (1.8.0):
    - React
  - RNScreens (2.5.0):
    - React
  - Yoga (1.14.0)
  - YogaKit (1.18.1):
    - Yoga (~> 1.14)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - DoubleConversion (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`)
  - FBLazyVector (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector`)
  - FBReactNativeSpec (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec`)
  - Firebase/Analytics
  - Flipper (~> 0.33.1)
  - Flipper-DoubleConversion (= 1.1.7)
  - Flipper-Folly (~> 2.1)
  - Flipper-Glog (= 0.3.6)
  - Flipper-PeerTalk (~> 0.0.4)
  - Flipper-RSocket (~> 1.0)
  - FlipperKit (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/Core (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/CppBridge (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FBCxxFollyDynamicConvert (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FBDefines (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FKPortForwarding (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitHighlightOverlay (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutTextSearchable (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin (~> 0.33.1)
  - FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin (~> 0.33.1)
  - Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`)
  - glog (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`)
  - RCTRequired (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired`)
  - RCTTypeSafety (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety`)
  - React (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)
  - React-Core (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)
  - React-Core/DevSupport (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)
  - React-Core/RCTWebSocket (from `../node_modules/react-native/`)
  - React-CoreModules (from `../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules`)
  - React-cxxreact (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact`)
  - React-jsi (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi`)
  - React-jsiexecutor (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor`)
  - React-jsinspector (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector`)
  - react-native-safe-area-context (from `../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context`)
  - React-RCTActionSheet (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS`)
  - React-RCTAnimation (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation`)
  - React-RCTBlob (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob`)
  - React-RCTImage (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image`)
  - React-RCTLinking (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS`)
  - React-RCTNetwork (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network`)
  - React-RCTSettings (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings`)
  - React-RCTText (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text`)
  - React-RCTVibration (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration`)
  - ReactCommon/callinvoker (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`)
  - ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon`)
  - "RNCMaskedView (from `../node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view`)"
  - RNGestureHandler (from `../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler`)
  - RNReanimated (from `../node_modules/react-native-reanimated`)
  - RNScreens (from `../node_modules/react-native-screens`)
  - Yoga (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga`)

SPEC REPOS:
  trunk:
    - boost-for-react-native
    - CocoaAsyncSocket
    - CocoaLibEvent
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
    - FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop
    - FirebaseInstallations
    - Flipper
    - Flipper-DoubleConversion
    - Flipper-Folly
    - Flipper-Glog
    - Flipper-PeerTalk
    - Flipper-RSocket
    - FlipperKit
    - GoogleAppMeasurement
    - GoogleDataTransport
    - GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
    - GoogleUtilities
    - nanopb
    - OpenSSL-Universal
    - PromisesObjC
    - YogaKit

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  DoubleConversion:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
  FBLazyVector:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  FBReactNativeSpec:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  Folly:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
  glog:
    :podspec: "../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec"
  RCTRequired:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  RCTTypeSafety:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  React:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/"
  React-Core:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/"
  React-CoreModules:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules"
  React-cxxreact:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact"
  React-jsi:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi"
  React-jsiexecutor:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor"
  React-jsinspector:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector"
  react-native-safe-area-context:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context"
  React-RCTActionSheet:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS"
  React-RCTAnimation:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation"
  React-RCTBlob:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob"
  React-RCTImage:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image"
  React-RCTLinking:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS"
  React-RCTNetwork:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network"
  React-RCTSettings:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings"
  React-RCTText:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text"
  React-RCTVibration:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration"
  ReactCommon:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  RNCMaskedView:
    :path: "../node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view"
  RNGestureHandler:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler"
  RNReanimated:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-reanimated"
  RNScreens:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native-screens"
  Yoga:
    :path: "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  boost-for-react-native: 39c7adb57c4e60d6c5479dd8623128eb5b3f0f2c
  CocoaAsyncSocket: 694058e7c0ed05a9e217d1b3c7ded962f4180845
  CocoaLibEvent: 2fab71b8bd46dd33ddb959f7928ec5909f838e3f
  DoubleConversion: 5805e889d232975c086db112ece9ed034df7a0b2
  FBLazyVector: 4aab18c93cd9546e4bfed752b4084585eca8b245
  FBReactNativeSpec: 5465d51ccfeecb7faa12f9ae0024f2044ce4044e
  Firebase: 32f9520684e87c7af3f0704f7f88042626d6b536
  FirebaseAnalytics: 83f822fd0d33a46f49f89b8c3ab16ab4d89df08a
  FirebaseCore: 9aca0f1fffb405176ba15311a5621fcde4106fcf
  FirebaseCoreDiagnostics: 13a6564cd6d5375066bbc8940cc1753af24497f3
  FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop: 296e2c5f5314500a850ad0b83e9e7c10b011a850
  FirebaseInstallations: acb3216eb9784d3b1d2d2d635ff74fa892cc0c44
  Flipper: 6c1f484f9a88d30ab3e272800d53688439e50f69
  Flipper-DoubleConversion: 38631e41ef4f9b12861c67d17cb5518d06badc41
  Flipper-Folly: c12092ea368353b58e992843a990a3225d4533c3
  Flipper-Glog: 1dfd6abf1e922806c52ceb8701a3599a79a200a6
  Flipper-PeerTalk: 116d8f857dc6ef55c7a5a75ea3ceaafe878aadc9
  Flipper-RSocket: 64e7431a55835eb953b0bf984ef3b90ae9fdddd7
  FlipperKit: 6dc9b8f4ef60d9e5ded7f0264db299c91f18832e
  Folly: 30e7936e1c45c08d884aa59369ed951a8e68cf51
  glog: 1f3da668190260b06b429bb211bfbee5cd790c28
  GoogleAppMeasurement: e49be3954045b17d046f271b9cc1ec052bad9702
  GoogleDataTransport: 6ffa4dd0b6d547f8d27b91bd92fa9e197a3f5f1f
  GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport: 2d7e609f8c5af1a33d7d59053e6f8cba59365df5
  GoogleUtilities: ad0f3b691c67909d03a3327cc205222ab8f42e0e
  nanopb: 18003b5e52dab79db540fe93fe9579f399bd1ccd
  OpenSSL-Universal: 8b48cc0d10c1b2923617dfe5c178aa9ed2689355
  PromisesObjC: c119f3cd559f50b7ae681fa59dc1acd19173b7e6
  RCTRequired: cec6a34b3ac8a9915c37e7e4ad3aa74726ce4035
  RCTTypeSafety: 93006131180074cffa227a1075802c89a49dd4ce
  React: 29a8b1a02bd764fb7644ef04019270849b9a7ac3
  React-Core: b12bffb3f567fdf99510acb716ef1abd426e0e05
  React-CoreModules: 4a9b87bbe669d6c3173c0132c3328e3b000783d0
  React-cxxreact: e65f9c2ba0ac5be946f53548c1aaaee5873a8103
  React-jsi: b6dc94a6a12ff98e8877287a0b7620d365201161
  React-jsiexecutor: 1540d1c01bb493ae3124ed83351b1b6a155db7da
  React-jsinspector: 512e560d0e985d0e8c479a54a4e5c147a9c83493
  react-native-safe-area-context: 8260e5157617df4b72865f44006797f895b2ada7
  React-RCTActionSheet: f41ea8a811aac770e0cc6e0ad6b270c644ea8b7c
  React-RCTAnimation: 49ab98b1c1ff4445148b72a3d61554138565bad0
  React-RCTBlob: a332773f0ebc413a0ce85942a55b064471587a71
  React-RCTImage: e70be9b9c74fe4e42d0005f42cace7981c994ac3
  React-RCTLinking: c1b9739a88d56ecbec23b7f63650e44672ab2ad2
  React-RCTNetwork: 73138b6f45e5a2768ad93f3d57873c2a18d14b44
  React-RCTSettings: 6e3738a87e21b39a8cb08d627e68c44acf1e325a
  React-RCTText: fae545b10cfdb3d247c36c56f61a94cfd6dba41d
  React-RCTVibration: 4356114dbcba4ce66991096e51a66e61eda51256
  ReactCommon: ed4e11d27609d571e7eee8b65548efc191116eb3
  RNCMaskedView: 5dba3cb07493765fb66156c83c3dd281ca709a48
  RNGestureHandler: 8f09cd560f8d533eb36da5a6c5a843af9f056b38
  RNReanimated: 955cf4068714003d2f1a6e2bae3fb1118f359aff
  RNScreens: ac02d0e4529f08ced69f5580d416f968a6ec3a1d
  Yoga: 3ebccbdd559724312790e7742142d062476b698e
  YogaKit: f782866e155069a2cca2517aafea43200b01fd5a

PODFILE CHECKSUM: ddc7d6c9cac170925f68656e3217289426c07041

COCOAPODS: 1.9.1
```

Thanks for your help!
Tim

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Run `pod update Firebase/Core`, and repeat for every problematic dependency.

The problem here is that the previously installed version of Firebase’s iOS library is different from the version that is required by the Native Module. The `pod install` command never updates Pods from versions listed in the lockfile.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that solved it. Is see that it downgraded some packages which is a bit weird, no?     <br/>         Installing Firebase 6.13.0 (was 6.22.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 6.1.6 (was 6.4.1 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing FirebaseAuth (6.4.2)
Installing FirebaseAuthInterop (1.1.0)
Installing FirebaseCore 6.4.0 (was 6.6.6 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)
Installing FirebaseCoreDiagnostics 1.2.4 (was 1.2.3 and source changed to

Comment: @Tlow Perhaps you had Firebase integrated before (without the React Native bindings)? And when you added the binding library, it requires a lower version Firebase lib?

Answer (score 1):

```
pod install --repo-update
```

using this command I resolve my issue